# Style glitch in MSE reviews

Tags: bug, review, design

In the review queues, the descending part of of the title is clipped off.  From https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/31096:

> [image: note the brackets and the g]

This particular screen shot was from Safari (7.0.6 9537.78.2) on a mac, but it it can also be seen with chrome and firefox (though again, viewed on a mac).

Not a big thing, just one of those things that annoys people.  I don't see anything obviously wrong in the styling for the text though I'm also not one familiar with the deep intricacies of css and joys of webkit.

Comment: Looks OK in Chrome running under Windows 7 so guess it's related to the OS. (probably font issue?)

Comment: Its not just *that* font though.  Playing with styles (this one is futura) the problem is reproducible: http://i.stack.imgur.com/t88mT.png

Comment: Hmm... turns out that if I remove the `font-size: 16px;` CSS rule applied on the element, I get this exact same glitch. Dunno how to connect the dots, but doubt it's a coincidence.

Comment: *question not found*